# Adding Custom Functions To A ERC20 Contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Im new to contract development and i'm looking for a bit of advice relating to my token contract?

1. First is it ok to add custom functions to an ERC20 contract?
2. Do I need to use all the functions listed on this example page? [Token Example](https://www.ethereum.org/token)
3. Is it ok to create a minting function within the ERC20 contract that only the owner can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. You need to implement all the functions here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md.
3. It's "okay" from the technical perspective of not breaking things. Depending on your use case, it may or may not be okay from economic and trust standpoints.